# What is the best way to go about designing a persistence model for many classes in C++ while also ensuring SOLID is followed?

Tags: c++, persistence, solid-principles

I've scoured the web for specific design information on how to effectively design a persistence model in for C++ classes and I've come up short. So I decided to ask it here.

Let's say I have 4 classes:

Class A

Class B

Class C

Class Persist

I want to persist classes A, B, and C to disk using the class "Persist" such that one file contains the config info for each class:

```
my_module.json
{
  A {
    ...
  },
  B {
    ...
  },
  C {
    ...
  }
}
```

My question is, what's the best approach to design this such that SOLID principles are followed?

For example, the single responsibility principle suggests that a class should have only one responsibility (or only one reason to change) and the Law of Demeter suggests that classes know as little of each other as possible.

So then:

1) Should a class know how to serialize itself or would that already violate single responsibility?

2) If I use a third party library like "cereal" to serialize "Class A", I will need to add tags to the internal members of "Class A" to show the engine how it should serialize. This increases coupling between "Class A" and the third party engine, which has to be bad right?

3) Should I instead use intermediate classes that translate the object from "Class A" into an object with proper tags that a third party library will understand? This removes any knowledge of serialization from "Class A", but it adds more complexity and more classes.

4) Should the class be aware of the persistence module? Is this realistic when trying to serialize? If so, how should the class notify the persistence module that state has changed and it's time to persist? Or should the persistence module simply poll the objects periodically for fresh configuration?

I'm fairly new to OO but deeply interested. Specifics on interactions between classes will be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: for anything else than academia principles should be taken with a grain of salt. They are principles because if you dont follow them you will face certain drawbacks. However, it isnt as simple as good vs bad. For example for 2) if you decide to use cereal then there is nothing bad about adding annotations to your classes, you just should be aware that once you did that you cannot switch easily to a different seriazataion framework (or some work is lost), this might be a major problem or it might be just ok... btw imho the question is too broad

Answer (score 0):

Generally in software engineering, decisions aren’t about principles, they’re about tradeoffs.

1 — it violates single responsibility, but in C++ you don’t have much choice. The language doesn’t natively supports runtime reflection, nor virtual constructors / class factories. Without these two features, it’s very hard to implement objects serialization without objects serializing themselves. By “very hard” I mean it requires external tooling, or lots of macros / templates, IMO very expensive to support long-term.

2 — it increases coupling, adds a lot of complexity (you’ll have to support any 3rd party library you’re using), but if you need to support multiple different serialization formats at once, e.g. both JSON, XML and binary, it could still be a good thing.

3 — depends but I would say “no”. The good format for intermediate representation is something DOM tree-like, and you’ll waste too much CPU time building that, because too many small RAM allocations and pointer chasing. If for some reason you want to design and support well-defined intermediate representation, I’d structured it as a pair of event-driven interfaces (one reader another writer), see [SAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML) for inspiration.

4 — Most serialization libraries are designed so that save/load is a one-time process. The reason for that is most modern generic serialization formats (XML, JSON, most binary formats) don’t support updates. You’ll have to write out a complete file anyway. Notifications only bring value when the storage format supports partial updates, e.g. if you’re saving/loading in an [embedded] database, not just in a JSON file. The common practice is, call save manually from the outside, every time you’ve finished modifying your objects. With automatic saves it’s easy to waste too much IO bandwidth and CPU time writing objects in some inconsistent intermediate states.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

For #4, unfortunately for my case, saving and loading needs to be periodic as well. Would you mind elaborating on how a class can notify the serial engine that it has finished modifying objects?

I suppose it would have to be aware of the serial engine to be able to inform it that object modification has completed correct? Are there generally preferred ways of mostly decoupling the serializing engine from the class that needs to be serialized?